# Get the next and before words from a word

Tags: php, mysql

I have tb words in a database :

```
=====================
= id = kata = posisi
=====================
= 1 = you   =  1         =
= 2 = should=  2         =
= 3 = eat   =  3 9 20    =
etc
```

Column posisi shows the positions of words in a sentence, that can be has 2 or more position for every word that I separated their position with space in its coloumn. The table comes from indexing process for sentence :

```
You should eat two bananas before lunch and eat two before your dinner and then consume one banana. i eat banana
```

I wanna get 5 words before and 5 next words from a keyword. 
for example I submit keyword `and` I will get result :

```
eat two bananas before lunch and eat two before your dinner
```

and

```
eat two before your dinner and then consume one banana. i
```

here's the code I've tried :

```
require_once 'connection.php';

function getPosition ($keyword) {
    $key = strtolower($keyword);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words WHERE kata = '$key' ") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $position = $row['posisi'];
    }
    return $position;
}

$key= 'And';
$and = getPosition($key);
$explode = explode (' ', $and);
foreach ($explode as $data => $datas){
    for ($i = 1 ; $i < 6 ;$i++){
        $nextdata[$i] = (int)$datas + $i;
        $databefore[$i] = (int)$datas - $i;

        $queryNext = mysql_query("SELECT kata FROM words WHERE posisi = '$nextdata[$i]' and posisi =$databefore[$i] ") or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryNext)) {
            $position = $row['kata'];
        }
        //print_r($position);

    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, maybe the problem is when it meet the column with has many position, it can't be read it. Please help me. Thank You :)

Comment: Explain “doesn't work”.

Comment: @Strawberry Must I make a new table for position?

Comment: You don't *have* to do anything, but normalization is a prerequisite of RDBMS use. And, yes, this problem becomes infinitely easier if you put position in a separate table.

Comment: BTW, that's probably too many bananas.